# Difficulty adding Maven Apache to system PATH

Tags: java, apache, maven, path, visual-studio-code

I've read through multiple posts regarding this issue and can't seem to find a solution that works for my situation. I've added JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME to my System Variables:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmv8Z.jpg

From there I added them to my PATH using %JAVA_HOME%\bin and %MAVEN_HOME%\bin:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwaRT.jpg

When I run cmd as an administrator and type "mvn -version" it returns an error saying:

"'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7dWX.jpg

I've tried different methods suggested by users and nothing has led to solution. Any advice would be appreciated. I'm also running Windows 10.

Comment: You need to add the bin folder to the path where the maven executable lies in.

Comment: Within my "apache-maven-3.6.0" folder where is the executable located? I've already tried searching around and could not find it.

Comment: You have to hold the shift key and then right click. Choose option 'Open command window here'. And then go for your command.

Comment: Do now use `MAVEN_HOME` only adding the bin folder into the PATH variable that's it.

Comment: @Mike I'm confused sorry, where am I right-clicking?

Comment: Right click anywhere on the window. This will work. But I suggest you to add MAVEN_HOME just as khmarbaise and Glains suggested.

Comment: <https://imgur.com/a/0FLy2pW>

Like this? Or am I misinterpreting.

Comment: I suppose you are not using a correct version of maven. Maven do not have a src folder. Kindly download a newer version of maven. The path will be something like `<yourMavenInstalledPath>/bin`

Comment: Version 3.6 is the latest version I believe.

https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: Kindly follow this https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have installed the wrong version of Apache Maven.

1. Install the binary version for Windows from [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi).
2. Then do the steps as you have done previously to set PATH and run
   Maven.
3. Ensure you open a new Command Prompt Window after setting PATH and
   running Maven.

Comment: This did it! Ran mvn -version in command prompt and verified that it is installed properly. Thank you to everyone for your responses.